# Como mostrar resultados de una base de datos en un radio button

Tags: php, formularios, radiobutton

El problema que tengo, es que cuando voy a modificar el registro de un funcionario tengo que mostrar el cargo que ocupa en la empresa y éste está con radio buttons.
¿Cómo hago para mostrar el valor que viene de la base de datos en un radio button con php?

Comment: Primero que nada, debes traer los datos necesarios. Asi que para ello debes tener tu consulta hecha. Luego, al radiobutton, le cargas los datos solicitados, ya sea como valor o texto.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada debes tener en cuenta que los input radio y checkbox se marcan a través de su atributo checked. El valor no es visible, lo que ves, es si este radio/checkbox esta seleccionado (checked) o no. Y esto lo logras agregando el atributo checked condicionalmente.

Para tu caso seria algo así:

```
        <?php foreach($tiposDeCargo as $tipoDeCargo): ?>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" 
                       name="cargo" 
                       value="<?php echo $tipoDeCargo['id']; ?>"
                       <?php if ($funcionario['tipo_de_cargo'] == $tipoDeCargo['id']): ?> checked <?php endif; ?>
                /> <?php echo $tipoDeCargo['nombre']; ?>
            </label>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Espero esto te ayude, buena suerte!